# Can I permanently add ssh private key to my user agent?

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

Somewhat of a noob question but everyday at work when I open git bash I have to start the ssh-agent daemon and I have to add my ssh-private key to the user-agent so that Github knows who I am.

1. eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
2. ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

If I dont do this I cannot pull/push to github.

It gets a little annoying to have to do this everyday, is there a way to add it permanently?

Comment: Most likely, you can simply put the two commands in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`. I don't know exactly what kind of environment Git bash will run  or run in, so there might be something more complicated you need to do to avoid running multiple instances of `ssh-agent`.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `ssh-agent`, put the following in your `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

An agent is primarily useful either to avoid creating a large number of configurations in `.ssh/config` (as any connection will attempt to use a key found in the agent), or for allowing remote SSH sessions to reach back to your local machine for necessary keys.

Comment: To restart ssh agent after the change: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/520343/238934

Comment: You don't need to restart the agent. Each invocation of `ssh` will read the configuration file. If you specify an explicit file, `ssh` will not need to check with the currently running agent.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that it solved myself the same problem, was moving the private key, e.g `id_rsa`, to the default ssh key location, `~/.ssh`.

```
cp /your/key/location/id_rsa ~/.ssh
```

It seems that for some reason, when you add an identity from a different location with the `-i` option of the `ssh-add` command, it doesn't add it permanently.

Comment: Mine is already there, but my file name is not a standard one like `id_rsa`, and that's causing the problem.